# Do I need to use a try-with-resource when using java's java.nio.file.readAllLines?

Tags: java, file-io, io, try-catch

when using java.nio.file.readAllLines, is there any need to close the resource?

I saw in some examples online that they don't do it.

For example here https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?class=java.nio.file.Files&method=readAllLines
They catch the IOException but they don't close any resource.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [documentation fo `Files`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html)?

Comment: The documentation for readAllLines mentions nothing about resource closing. just don't understand if it should be done or not.

Comment: Other question: do you see a `close()`-method?

Comment: I don’t understand what’s missing from this question. It is poorly researched, yes, but to me it’s perfectly clear, makes great sense and may be useful to other readers now and in the future. Might those who voted to close or downvoted please explain? For us all to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR: no.**

As Turing85 hinted in the comments, it is in the documentation.

The example that you linked to is using the one-arg `Files.readAllLines()`. The documentation of that method says:

> This method works as if invoking it were equivalent to evaluating the
>   expression:
>
> ```
>     Files.readAllLines(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
> ```

The documentation of the two-arg method referred to here says:

> This method ensures that the file is closed when all bytes have been
>   read or an I/O error, or other runtime exception, is thrown.

So no, there is no need for you to do anything to close the file or other resources. So the example that you read is complete and correct on this point.

**Documentation links**

- [`Files.readAllLines(Path)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path))
- [`Files.readAllLines(Path, Charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.charset.Charset))

Answer (score 1):

In the Files class 'readAllLines(path)' method throws 'IOException' in some cases it will throws Exception here you can catch the Exception and send proper error message to end user.Other wise may you need to face runtime issues.

```
    Path Path = null;
    try {
    Files.readAllLines(Path);
    }catch (IOException e) {

        //write your error message logic
    }
```